# Tooltip on anchor's title not shown in IE9

Tags: html, tooltip, internet-explorer-9, anchor

Has something was changed in the way IE9 treats the **title** attribute in an anchor tag?
I try to use a regular anchor, such as -

```
<a href="http://www.somelink.com" title="Some title here">This is a link</a>
```

A tooltip should be with the title is expected to appear, and it does appear in previous versions of IE and also in other browsers, but not on IE9. 
Is there a know issue with that? I tried to search the web for that, but found nothing about this.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: I cannot replicate your issue. Assuming the tags are the main content of the page, in IE9 the tooltips show up fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code for the href link above works fine in IE9. Which leads me to believe something else on the page is causing the issue. Have you tried validating your html? http://validator.w3.org/

It could be that there's something else broken that the other browsers are just looking past. Perhaps it's nested in such a way that's causing IE9 to overlook the tag.

Comment: I've tried to validate the page, there are 8 errors but in other places of the page and not relevant to the anchors. This is a page of a long tag cloud (about 500 tags, each tag is a link). You may look at the page, it is in Hebrew, but anyway you can hover on each link and see that in IE9 there is no tooltip, and others do have. This is the actual page - http://tv.social.org.il/tags

Comment: I am seeing the title on a links in IE9 on your site working. Try this, open your page in IE9 and hit f12. Look to see if you are in IE9 compatibility mode, Quirks or IE7 mode? ...or perhaps it's caused by a browser toolbar you have installed? If you have a toolbar, try unistalling it to see if it works.

Comment: I myself do not have IE9, but I checked today in 2 pcs and it is working also. For some reason, in the client's PC with IE9 it happens, I will try to get him check his PC, but I'm glad to know it is not a problem in the site or another issue of IE9. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

I have encountered this problem in a few applications I've worked on.

I've found it doesn't work if you have nested elements within the element with the title.

The example below doesn't show its title in IE9 for me:

```
<a href="test.html" title="test tooltip"><span>test link</span></a>
```

However, this example does work:

```
<a href="test.html" title="test tooltip">test link</a>
```

That is with an XHTML 1.0 Transitional doctype and Browser Mode: IE9 and Document Mode: IE9 Standards.

Obviously your example doesn't have a nested element but thought it might be relevant to some people who find this post based on the title.

You can overcome this limitation in IE by specifying the nested element to be an inline-block:

```
a span {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: More relevant answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246818/title-tooltip-is-not-shown-when-span-is-child-of-anchor

Comment: As the text says, this does not apply to the code in the question, so it is not an answer (to the question asked).

Answer (score 1):

I have found a good work-around, Place your title in an abbr tag. I've tested this in Safari, Chrome, IE9, and Firefox. It works in all of them.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to put at least one character outside the inner tags:

```
<a href="#" title="Tooltip"><font color="blue">This does not work</font></a>
<a href="#" title="Tooltip"><font color="blue">This</font> <font color="blue">does work</font></a>
```

Comment: Why have you used deprecated font tags in your example? I know it was a few years ago but font tags have been deprecated since HTML 4 which was a W3C Recommendation released in Dec 1997!

Answer (score 0):

I had a typical scenario wherein we had to show a image with tooltip. The image was inside a Iframe and tooltips were not being displayed, when opened in a Browser with IE 10 Compat Mode.

The alt tag helped me out. The solution was to set the images alt tag.

```html
<A onclick=navigate() title="Did not work" href="javascript:void(0);" height="" width="">
  <IMG alt="This worked" src="http://img.webmd.com/dtmcms/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/icons/imageviewer_back_button.gif">
</A>
```